# Debbug react native utilizando atach process no VS Code

Tags: react-native

Boa noite pessoa, tem dias que estou tentando debbugar uma aplicação no vs code coisa que pelo Android Studio é relativamente fácil e o debbug pelo navegador nao esta funcionando bem para mim.

Acredito que o problema esteja na parte do atach
No android studio basta clicar em atach debbuger e selecionar a opção da imagem
[image]

Porem em tudo que encontrei para o vs code, o por padrão é indicado incluir a extenção "React native tools"
e em cada tutorial ele da uma instrução do que criar no launch.json

porem nenhuma realmente funciona...

Atualmente estou tentando esta

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "attach",            
    }
]
```

}

Agradeço se alguém tiver alguma solução.